# How to call a variable linked to an option value within a JSP page

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

I have a few option values within my JSP page. I want to trigger a query based on what option value is chosen. Basically if the option value selected is either 33 or 36, execute one query, else execute the other query. Please see sample code below:

```
    <table border="0" align='center'>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <h2>Division</h2>
            </td>
            <td align='left'>
            <jsp:useBean id="masterDaoUtil" class="master.dao.util.MasterDataConstants"/>
            <select name="divisionId" id="divisionId">
            <option value="33"><%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_AUDIT_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
            <option value="31"><%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_CHANGE_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
            <option value="34"><%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_DEA_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
            <option value="35"><%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_EHS_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
            <option value="23"><%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_EVENT_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
            <option value="36"><%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_QUALITY_EVENT_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
            <option value="40"><%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_NORAMCO_AUDIT_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
            <option value="43"><%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_NORAMCO_CHANGE_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
            <option value="41"><%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_NORAMCO_DEA_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
            <option value="42"><%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_NORAMCO_EHS_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
            <option value="44"><%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_NORAMCO_EVENT_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h2>Site Name</h2>
            </td>
            <td align='left'>
            <jsp:useBean id="masterDao" class="master.dao.MasterDataDao"/>
            <select name="siteId" id="siteId">
            <option value="0">ALL</option>
            ****<%if (divisionId == 33 | divisionId == 36) {%>
             <c:forEach items="${masterDao.allJJSites}" var="siteDto">
             <option value="${siteDto.id}">${siteDto.name}</option>
            </c:forEach>
            <%} else { %>
             <c:forEach items="${masterDao.allSites}" var="siteDto">
             <option value="${siteDto.id}">${siteDto.name}</option>
            </c:forEach>
            <% } %>****
            </select></td>
        </tr>


    </table>
```

I have tried to make my if-else clause bold but not sure if it is showing. Basically it is located where the **** is. Obviously I cannot use divisionId as a variable but I wanted to know how I can either set a variable to the option value selected or see if there was another way to do this.

Comment: Basically this would be a dependency dropdown. The division selected on the first dropdown will trigger which values will show for the second dropdown. Any ideas?

Comment: I guess this one can't be answered. I will see if this can be done another way. Thanks